# how to calculate angle between two vectors code in php

Tags: php, math, linear-algebra

I want to find the angle between the vector

> v1 = [-1,-2]

and

> v2 = [90,-5]

[here solution given how to calculate angle  (mathematics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227014/find-the-angle-between-two-vectors?rq=1)

in php code need to calculate angle between two vector  `[-1,-2] and [90,-5]`.
Need php code.

Thanks

Comment: It's less of a PHP question than a math question

Comment: The answer by @Licson below is a better answer. It returns an angle in $(-180,180]$ unlike the answer below that uses $\arccos$. I don not understand why that answer got a negative vote.

Comment: Agree. The arccos answer will return an angle modulo pi radians, which throws away "directional" information about the two points.

Comment: I found this answer looking for the wrong question. Maybe it will help others to clarify: Are you looking for the angle between to vectors OR are you looking for the angle between the line between to vectors (points) and the X-axis? This question is about the first option. (Or at least, the answers are)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function norm($vec)
{
    $norm = 0;
    $components = count($vec);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $components; $i++)
        $norm += $vec[$i] * $vec[$i];

    return sqrt($norm);
}

function dot($vec1, $vec2)
{
    $prod = 0;
    $components = count($vec1);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $components; $i++)
        $prod += ($vec1[$i] * $vec2[$i]);

    return $prod;
}
```

And to calculate the actual angle:

```
$v1 = array(-1, -2);
$v2 = array(90, -5);

$ang = acos(dot($v1, $v2) / (norm($v1) * norm($v2)));

echo $ang; // angle in radians
> 1.97894543055
```

Comment: if $v1 = array(0, 0);
$v2 = array(-1, 0); is this and we get error division by zero. what to do at that time

Comment: You can't have an angle between a zero vector and another. So you could just add a check on your input vectors to ensure that neither are zero vectors (ie not [0, 0, 0]).

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `atan2($y,$x)` function in php to do it.
which find angle in radian.

```
<?php
$angle = rad2deg(atan2($y2-$y1,$x2-$x1));
//$angle is in degrees
?>
```

Comment: With `$x1 = 2; $y1 = 0; $x2 = 2; $y2 = 2;` this throw °90. It should be °45, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

The angle of two vectors is calculated by

```
       v1X * v2X + v1Y * v2Y
acos(--------------------------) = angle between two vectors.
           |v1| * |v2|
```

You can use this formula directly in PHP.

Note:

`|v1|` and `|v2|` are the length of the vectors and are calculated using Pythagoras's Theorem.

```
|v1| = sqrt(v1X * v1X + v1Y * v1Y)
|v2| = sqrt(v2X * v2X + v2Y * v2Y)
```